How do I transfer Data ( including Images ) from Angular client side to ASP.NET API server Side?
I've final project coming up soon, and well I'm nearly ending what I need to be done. I've just got stuck on this part. I had a method which took Hotel's information like HotelName stores rooms and addresses (which has like roomname, price and address has like country city). Well it worked great, sent post request and added to database, but I got stuck on adding images.
Basically what I wanted to do was that I wanted to upload file from client side, send the file to server side on server side save them to a specific folder and generate their URL and save Room's Images URL to RoomsImagesTb on database and Hotel's Images URLs to HotelImagesTb on database
It is like: Hotel can have images, and hotel also can have many rooms and those each rooms can have many images etc. (hotel also can have many addresses)
Note: It worked before I added Images. it is getting stuck to a part where it should send a post method and it doesn't send. (I get BAD request 400 when I click on add Hotel)

I will just show you the client side first.
So here are my Dtos
AddHotelDto
import { AddAdressDto } from "./AddAdressDto";
import { AddRoomDto } from "./AddRoomDto";

export interface AddHotelDto {
  hotelName: string;
  stars: number;
  hotelAdresses: AddAdressDto[] | null;
  rooms: AddRoomDto[] | null;
  hotelImages: File[] | null; 
}

AddRoomDto
export interface AddRoomDto {
  name: string,
  description: string,
  price: number
  roomImages: File[] | null;
}


AddAdressesDto
export interface AddAdressDto {
  country: string,
  city: string,
  street: string
}


**AddHotelComponent.ts **
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AddAdressDto } from "../AddAdressDto";
import { AddRoomDto } from "../AddRoomDto";
import { AddHotelDto } from '../AddHotelDto';
import { HotelService } from '../../hotel.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-hotel',
  templateUrl: './add-hotel.component.html',
  styleUrl: './add-hotel.component.css'
})
export class AddHotelComponent {
  hotel: AddHotelDto = {
    hotelName: '',
    stars: 0,
    hotelAdresses: [],
    rooms: [],
    hotelImages: []
  };
  hotelImages: File[] = [];
  roomImagesMap: Map<number, File[]> = new Map<number, File[]>() //Map to store room images by id.


  showAdressForm = false;
  addedAddress: AddAdressDto[] = [];

  showRoomForm = false;
  addedRooms: AddRoomDto[] = [];

  constructor(private hotelService: HotelService, private router: Router) { }

  AddHotel() {
    

    this.hotel.rooms = this.addedRooms;
    this.hotel.hotelAdresses = this.addedAddress;
    this.hotel.hotelImages = this.hotelImages;
    this.hotel.rooms = this.addedRooms;



    let formData = new FormData();

    let k: keyof AddHotelDto;
    for (k in this.hotel) {
      if (k === "hotelAdresses") {
        if (this.hotel[k]) {
          let hotelAdresses = this.hotel[k]!;
          let keyHA: keyof AddAdressDto;
          for (let i = 0; i < hotelAdresses.length; i++) {
            let hotelAddress = hotelAdresses[i];
            for (keyHA in hotelAddress) {
              formData.append(`${k}[${i}].${keyHA}`, hotelAddress[keyHA]);
            }
          }
        }
      } else if (k === "rooms") {
        if (this.hotel[k]) {
          let rooms = this.hotel[k]!;
          let keyAR: keyof AddRoomDto;
          for (let i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
            let room = rooms[i];
            for (keyAR in room) {
              if (keyAR === "roomImages") {
                let roomImages = room[keyAR];
                if (roomImages) {
                  for (let j = 0; j < roomImages.length; j++) {
                    formData.append(`${k}[${i}].${keyAR}[${j}]`, roomImages[j]);
                  }
                }
              } else {
                formData.append(`${k}[${i}].${keyAR}`, room[keyAR].toString());
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else if (k === "hotelImages") {
        if (this.hotel[k]) {
          let hotelImages = this.hotel[k];
          if (hotelImages) {
            for (let i = 0; i < hotelImages.length; i++) {
              formData.append(`${k}[${i}]`, hotelImages[i]);
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        formData.append(k, this.hotel[k].toString());
      }
    }

    const formDataObject: Record<string, string> = {};

    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      formDataObject[key] = value.toString(); // Convert to string if needed
    });

    const formDataJSON = JSON.stringify(formDataObject, null, 2);
    console.log('FormData:', formDataJSON);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.hotel))

    this.hotelService.addHotel(formData).subscribe(

      response => {
        console.log("GETS IN ADDHOTEL SUCCESS CLIENT")
        if (response.hotelId != 0) {
          this.router.navigate([`/`]);
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log("GETS IN ERROR OF ADDHOTEL")
        console.error('Error adding hotel:', error);
      }
    )
  }




    

  onRoomAdded(roomEvent: AddRoomDto) {
    const room: AddRoomDto = roomEvent as AddRoomDto;
    console.log(room);
    if (room != undefined) {
      this.addedRooms.push(room);
    }
    this.showRoomForm = false; // Hide the room form
  }

  onAdressAdded(adressEvent: AddAdressDto) {

    const adress: AddAdressDto = adressEvent as AddAdressDto;
    console.log(adress);
    if (adress != undefined) {
      this.addedAddress.push(adress);
    }
    this.showAdressForm = false; // Hide the adress form
  }

  onHotelImagesSelected(event: any) {
    this.hotelImages = Array.from(event.target.files);
  }

}



hotelService.ts
export class HotelService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://localhost:7071/Hotel';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }


  getHotels(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrl}`).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        console.log("response: " + response);
        return response;
      })
    );
  }
  getHotel(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/${id}`,).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        console.log("RESPONSE OF GETTING INDIVIDUAL HOTEL: " + response);
        return response;
      })
    );
  }


  addHotel(hotel: AddHotelDto): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl, hotel);
  }

  //addHotel(hotel: AddHotelDto): Observable<any> {
  //  console.log("GETS IN ADDHOTEL SERVICE CLIENT")
  //  return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}`, JSON.stringify(hotel)).pipe(//<-PART IT GETS STUCK ON

  //    map(response => {

  //      console.log("GETS IN MAP METHOD IN ADDHOTEL SERVICE CLIENT")

  //      return response;

  //    })

  //  )
  //}
}


**
And here is API part. (ASP.NET API + IDENTITY)
**
HotelModel:

    public class Hotel
    {
        [Key]
        public int HotelId { get; set; }
        //hotel name
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
        public string HotelName { get; set; }
        [Range(1,5,ErrorMessage = "Hotel Star Rating Value Must be in between of 1 and 5.")]
        public byte Stars { get; set; }

        //hotel adress linked to Hotel class.
        public virtual ICollection<Adress> HotelAdresses { get; set; }

        //hotel rooms linked to hotel class.
        public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
        // Collection to represent the many-to-many relationship with QvookerUser
        public virtual ICollection<UserRoomBooking> BookedRooms { get; set; } = new List<UserRoomBooking>();
        // Navigation property to relate Hotel to its images
        public virtual ICollection<HotelImage> HotelImages { get; set; }

    }



HotelImage Model:
public class HotelImage
{
    [Key]
    public int HotelImageId { get; set; }

    public int HotelId { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HotelId")]
    public virtual Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
}

Room Model:
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(50)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(250)")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    //one to many.
    [ForeignKey("hotel")]
    public int HotelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Hotel hotel { get; set; }

    // Collection to represent the many-to-many relationship with UserRoomBooking
    public virtual ICollection<UserRoomBooking> BookedByUsers { get; set; } = new List<UserRoomBooking>();
    // Navigation property to relate Room to its images
    public virtual ICollection<RoomImage> RoomImages { get; set; }
}

**And well same thing goes for RoomImage class (same as HotelImage class)
now DTOs **
public class HotelDTO
{
    //hotel name
    public string HotelName { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 5, ErrorMessage = "Hotel Star Rating Value Must be in between of 1 and 5.")]
    public byte Stars { get; set; }

    public ICollection<IFormFile> HotelImages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AdressDTO> HotelAdresses { get; set; }

    //hotel rooms linked to hotel class.
    public virtual ICollection<RoomDTO> Rooms { get; set; }
}

public class RoomDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IFormFile> RoomImages { get; set; }
}

**Not showing adresses because it is not as important as rooms and hotels (it doesn't contain images)
Db Context:**
public class QvookerDbContext : IdentityDbContext<QvookerUser>
{
    public QvookerDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    //Adding HotelsTb
    public DbSet<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }
    //Adding AdressesTb
    public DbSet<Adress> Adresses { get; set; }
    //Adding RoomsTb
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    //Adding UsersTb
    public DbSet<QvookerUser> qvookerUsers { get; set; }
    //relation of qvookerUser and Hotel (for booking)
    public DbSet<UserRoomBooking> UserRoomBookings { get; set; }
    // Adding DbSet for HotelImage
    public DbSet<HotelImage> HotelImages { get; set; }

    // Adding DbSet for RoomImage
    public DbSet<RoomImage> RoomImages { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Configure primary key for UserRoomBooking entity
        builder.Entity<UserRoomBooking>()
            .HasKey(urb => new { urb.QvookerUserId, urb.RoomId, urb.StartDate });

        // Configure relationship with QvookerUser
        builder.Entity<UserRoomBooking>()
            .HasOne(urb => urb.QvookerUser)
            .WithMany(u => u.UserRoomBookings)
            .HasForeignKey(urb => urb.QvookerUserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        // Configure relationship with Room
        builder.Entity<UserRoomBooking>()
            .HasOne(urb => urb.Room)
            .WithMany(r => r.BookedByUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(urb => urb.RoomId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        // Configure relationship with Hotel
        builder.Entity<UserRoomBooking>()
            .HasOne(urb => urb.Hotel)
            .WithMany(h => h.BookedRooms)
            .HasForeignKey(urb => urb.HotelId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        // Configure required properties
        builder.Entity<UserRoomBooking>()
            .Property(urb => urb.StartDate)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Entity<UserRoomBooking>()
            .Property(urb => urb.EndDate)
            .IsRequired();

        // Add check constraint for date range
        builder.Entity<UserRoomBooking>()
            .HasCheckConstraint("CK_UserRoomBooking_Dates", "[EndDate] > [StartDate]");
    }

}

And finally the Hotel Controller:
  // POST: api/Hotel
 [Authorize]
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult<HotelDTO>> postHotel([FromForm] HotelDTO hotelDto)
 {
     //getting Response.
     ServiceResponse<HotelDTO> response = await _hotelService.AddHotel(hotelDto);
     //depending on response generating respond.
     if (!response.ServiceSuccess)
     {
         return NotFound(response);
     }
     if (response.ServiceSuccess)
     {
         return Ok(response.Data);
     }
     else
     {
         return BadRequest(response);
     }
 }

Hotel Service's AddHotel
 public async Task<ServiceResponse<HotelDTO>> AddHotel([FromForm] HotelDTO hotelDto)
 {
     //creating service's response instance.
     ServiceResponse<HotelDTO> serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<HotelDTO>();
     try
     {
         //creating hotel entity
         var hotel = new Hotel
         {
             HotelName = hotelDto.HotelName,
             Stars = hotelDto.Stars,
             HotelAdresses = hotelDto.HotelAdresses?.Select(x => _mapper.Map<Adress>(x)).ToList(),
             Rooms = new List<Room>(), // Initialize room collection
             HotelImages = new List<HotelImage>() // Initialize hotel image collection
         };
         // Save hotel entity to database
         _context.Hotels.Add(hotel);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

         // Save hotel images to folder and create URLs
         var hotelImageUrls = await SaveImagesAndGetUrls(hotelDto.HotelImages);

         // Create HotelImage entities and associate them with the hotel
         foreach (var imageUrl in hotelImageUrls)
         {
             var hotelImage = new HotelImage
             {
                 ImageUrl = imageUrl,
                 HotelId = hotel.HotelId
             };
             _context.HotelImages.Add(hotelImage);
         }

         // Save room entities with images
         foreach (var roomDto in hotelDto.Rooms)
         {
             var room = new Room
             {
                 Name = roomDto.Name,
                 Description = roomDto.Description,
                 price = roomDto.price,
                 HotelId = hotel.HotelId
             };

             hotel.Rooms.Add(room);
             _context.Rooms.Add(room);
             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

             var roomImageUrls = await SaveImagesAndGetUrls(roomDto.RoomImages);

             // Create RoomImage entities and associate them with the room
             foreach (var imageUrl in roomImageUrls)
             {
                 var roomImage = new RoomImage
                 {
                     ImageUrl = imageUrl,
                     RoomId = room.RoomId
                 };
                 _context.RoomImages.Add(roomImage);
             }
         }

         // Save changes to the database
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
         //Configure service Response
         serviceResponse.ServiceSuccess = true;
         var gettingHotel = await GetHotel(hotel.HotelId);
         serviceResponse.Data = _mapper.Map<HotelDTO>(gettingHotel);
         // Return the service Response.
         return serviceResponse;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         //In case there is an error.
         serviceResponse.errorMessage = e.Message;
         serviceResponse.ServiceSuccess = false;
         serviceResponse.Description = e.InnerException.ToString();
         return serviceResponse;
     }

 }

(I tried using formData on client side but failed.)
(I also wish to know what would be the best practice to achive what I want.)
(if needed, I am using Angular on front + bootstrap and asp.net API + entityframework on the back)
as for the question which is a bit similiar to mine doesn't help me at all, first it takes only one file in my case I want to send an Object
Hotel
which can have many hotelimages
which can have many rooms {
which can have many room images
}
which can have many addresses
also it is kinda confusing that for hotelimages it takes file and for rooms images it takes string array.

Debug:



and then we get this in a console.log

(debug doesn't go to controller on server-side, right away puts error)
After using Formdata:

 AddHotel() {
   

   this.hotel.rooms = this.addedRooms;
   this.hotel.hotelAdresses = this.addedAddress;
   this.hotel.hotelImages = this.hotelImages;
   this.hotel.rooms = this.addedRooms;



   let formData = new FormData();

   let k: keyof AddHotelDto;
   for (k in this.hotel) {
     if (k === "hotelAdresses") {
       if (this.hotel[k]) {
         let hotelAdresses = this.hotel[k]!;
         let keyHA: keyof AddAdressDto;
         for (let i = 0; i < hotelAdresses.length; i++) {
           let hotelAddress = hotelAdresses[i];
           for (keyHA in hotelAddress) {
             formData.append(`${k}[${i}].${keyHA}`, hotelAddress[keyHA]);
           }
         }
       }
     } else if (k === "rooms") {
       if (this.hotel[k]) {
         let rooms = this.hotel[k]!;
         let keyAR: keyof AddRoomDto;
         for (let i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
           let room = rooms[i];
           for (keyAR in room) {
             if (keyAR === "roomImages") {
               let roomImages = room[keyAR];
               if (roomImages) {
                 for (let j = 0; j < roomImages.length; j++) {
                   formData.append(`${k}[${i}].${keyAR}[${j}]`, roomImages[j]);
                 }
               }
             } else {
               formData.append(`${k}[${i}].${keyAR}`, room[keyAR].toString());
             }
           }
         }
       }
     } else if (k === "hotelImages") {
       if (this.hotel[k]) {
         let hotelImages = this.hotel[k];
         if (hotelImages) {
           for (let i = 0; i < hotelImages.length; i++) {
             formData.append(`${k}[${i}]`, hotelImages[i]);
           }
         }
       }
     } else {
       formData.append(k, this.hotel[k].toString());
     }
   }

   const formDataObject: Record<string, string> = {};

   formData.forEach((value, key) => {
     formDataObject[key] = value.toString(); // Convert to string if needed
   });

   const formDataJSON = JSON.stringify(formDataObject, null, 2);
   console.log('FormData:', formDataJSON);

   console.log(JSON.stringify(this.hotel))

   this.hotelService.addHotel(formData).subscribe(

     response => {
       console.log("GETS IN ADDHOTEL SUCCESS CLIENT")
       if (response.hotelId != 0) {
         this.router.navigate([`/`]);
       }
     },
     error => {
       console.log("GETS IN ERROR OF ADDHOTEL")
       console.error('Error adding hotel:', error);
     }
   )
 }

hotelservice addhotel()
     addHotel(hotel: FormData): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, hotel);
 }

From Last Debug I found out this:


Does this answer your question? Failed to send picture to Web API from Angular

I'll check it out.

I can't get it to work with formData
First because in that case I have to transfer Everything to strings and I get stuck on that ( I tried it too)
I just want to send an object. which contains every file

What error did you get when posting FormData?

exact same error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
|||||||AND THEN||||||||
add-hotel.component.ts:94
Error adding hotel:
HttpErrorResponse
(anonymous) @ add-hotel.component.ts:94
Zone - XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:load (async)
AddHotel @ add-hotel.component.ts:84
AddHotelComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_8_listener @ add-hotel.component.html:9
Zone - HTMLFormElement.addEventListener:submit (async)
AddHotelComponent_Template @ add-hotel.component.html:8
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ main.ts:5

I've added a bit more details that could be a help

I've added debug too, so it is more understandable.

As for this question, I've finally fixed it, and here is it:
Checking on Network I would get that roomsImages and hotelImages were empty.
so solution was:

do not use [(ngModel)] on type="file" in HTML Forms.

my API was waiting for "RoomImages" and not "roomImages[0]" (same for hotelImages)
so in this part removing part which showed index was solution:


    for (let j = 0; j < roomImages.length; j++) {
        formData.append(`${k}[${i}].${keyAR}[${j}]`, roomImages[j]);
    }


use the right way to handle from API side.
post should've taken this instead of HotelDTO hoteldto

[FromForm] HotelDTO hotelDto


This is tricky as you have nested arrays and objects. You need to construct the FormData instance in order to send the data with file(s) as below:
addHotel(hotel: AddHotelDto) : Observable<any> {
  let formData = new FormData();

  let k: keyof AddHotelDto;
  for (k in hotel) {
    if (k === "hotelAdresses") {
      if (hotel[k]) {
        let hotelAdresses = hotel[k]!;
        let keyHA: keyof AddAdressDto;
        for (let i = 0; i < hotelAdresses.length; i++) {
          let hotelAddress = hotelAdresses[i];
          for (keyHA in hotelAddress) {
            formData.append(`${k}[${i}].${keyHA}`, hotelAddress[keyHA]);
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (k === "rooms") {
      if (hotel[k]) {
        let rooms = hotel[k]!;
        let keyAR: keyof AddRoomDto;
        for (let i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
          let room = rooms[i];
          for (keyAR in room) {
            if (keyAR === "roomImages") {
              let roomImages = room[keyAR];
              if (roomImages) {
                for (let j = 0; j < roomImages.length; j++) {
                  formData.append(`${k}[${i}].${keyAR}[${j}]`, roomImages[j]);
                }
              }
            } else {
              formData.append(`${k}[${i}].${keyAR}`, room[keyAR].toString());
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (k === "hotelImages") {
      if (hotel[k]) {
        let hotelImages = hotel[k];
        if (hotelImages) {
          for (let i = 0; i < hotelImages.length; i++) {
            formData.append(`${k}[${i}]`, hotelImages[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      formData.append(k, hotel[k].toString());
    }
  }

  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, formData);
}


yeah it still doesn't send request it says
Bad request 400
(hovewer formdata forms well)

I will add the error picture in question.

yes, I've added in the question the way I added it, I mean formData is working it forms the variable and as you can see in console.log I added way to json view it and it looks good, thing is it erros exect moment when it should send on debug it doesn't even goes on api

only thing different from your code and mine is that I use hotelService from where I request the post you do it inside the method I do it seperately. but well this has nothing to do with it...

and I've updated the question and provided all the information that could be needed

I've recreated hotelcontroller too (still errors) i mean I know error wasn't there but still for cleaner code.

I've actually found out something useful, check the question's last part, I uploaded what I found out on last debug session. it looks like formdata isn't quite working. both Images arrays are empty.

your comment helped me however I solved what was actually wrong with it.
